# FatalErrorException in web.php line 23: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ']'

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

FatalErrorException in web.php line 23:
syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ']'

```
 Route::get('/' , ['as' => '/' , 'uses'=>loginController@getlogin]);
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses'=>loginController@postlogin]);

Route::get('/logout' ,['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>loginController@getLogout]);

Route::group(['middleware'=>['authen','roles']],function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard',['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>dashboardController@dashboard]);
});
```

i don't know what the problem ..  it shows FatalErrorException in web.php line 23:
syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ']'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uses` value must be string:

```
Route::get('/' , ['as' => '/' , 'uses'=> 'loginController@getlogin']);
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses'=>'loginController@postlogin']);

Route::get('/logout' ,['as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'loginController@getLogout']);

Route::group(['middleware'=>['authen','roles']],function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard',['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@dashboard']);
});
```

Comment: @prakashpokhrel i think you should accept this answer

Comment: sir can you tell me , how to know in laravel  which file contain error .. lots of time i cant find my error containing file :)

Comment: sure sir , i will

Comment: Laravel log files stored in storage/logs folder. [laravel errors docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors)